# PHP value keeps being NULL in next function

Tags: php, function, selenium

I'm trying to fix a test but somehow my value keeps being `NULL` in the next function.
I'm using the Selenium webdriver from Sebastian Bergmann.

So what I have:

```
protected $role;

// Setup .... 

public function testRoles()
{ 
// Code .... 
$this->role = 'hr'; // I want this value in the next function
}

public function testAcl()
{
// Login here
var_dump($this->role); // This var_dump is NULL , why?
$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys($this->role);
}
```

When I `var_dump` `$this->role` it gives `NULL`

**Question:** why is this? What did I forget/can do so it becomes the data I want: `'hr'`?

The error I'm getting: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`
It's because `$this->role` is `NULL`

Comment: You never called testRoles() before testAcl() ?

Comment: Are you are calling `testRoles()` and `testAcl()` in the same page cycle, in the correct order

Comment: Yea It calls it before, I currently found a workaround and made a private function

Comment: Then please post your workaround as an answer, as this seems very odd

Comment: @user574632 , jens-andré's answer solved it beter then my workaround.

Comment: Though small question, what's the difference btw doing  $this->role; and  $this->testRoles(); here? Shouldn't both work since I have a protected $role; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call testRoles() to set $this-roles...

```
   public function testAcl()
   {
       // call testRoles
       $this->testRoles();

       // now $this->role was set to hr by testRoles()

       // work with it
       var_dump($this->role); 
    }
```

Comment: Ok I see what I did wrong I was doing `$this->testRoles();` on the wrong place, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

it's because you never set the role before var_dump($this->role); line. That means that you have to run the $this->testRoles() before var_dump($this->role);.

Comment: Ok I see what I did wrong I was doing $this->testRoles(); on the wrong place, thanks for pointing it out